# PostgreSql find nth number

Tags: postgresql

Write an aggregate that finds the third largest integer in a column?
This is what i am doing:

```
create function third_step(bigint, integer) returns bigint AS
$$

SELECT distinct
 * from count_lab order by ab asc limit 1 offset 2 ;


$$ language sql; --can we use plpgsql somehow?

create aggregate third_agg(integer)
(stype=bigint,sfunc=third_step,initcond=0); 
SELECT distinct
 * from count_lab order by ab asc limit 1 offset 2  ;
```

Comment: I thought you had learned something... You will have to use a state variable that can hold the last three values and a transition function that shifts them.

Comment: @ laurenz i guess i fixed it..too much guess work though

Comment: `select distinct * ` makes no sense - the distinct will never remove duplicates as you also select the primary key column(s) of the table. I also don't see why your function needs parameters if should always return the "third largest" value (and nothing else)

Comment: @ horse its making a difference trust me or try it, will make better sense to you then

Comment: _If_ it makes a difference your table has no primary key - which is most probably a bad design to begin with. https://rextester.com/MOOI16752

Answer (score 0):

create function third_step(integer, ab integer) returns integer AS
$$

SELECT distinct
 * from count_lab order by ab asc limit 1 offset 2 ;

$$ language sql; --can we use plpgsql somehow?

create aggregate third_agg(integer)
(stype=integer,sfunc=third_step,initcond=0); 
SELECT distinct
 * from count_lab order by ab asc limit 1 offset 2  ;

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ab 
    FROM count_lab 
    WHERE ab IS NOT NULL 
    ORDER BY ab DESC 
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;
```